# Jquery appendTo, remove multiple divs

Tags: jquery, appendto

I'm new to jquery and am totally lost on this. I've searched quite a bit without success. Here's what I'm trying to do:

I am appending a (hidden) div in one area to another div up several levels in the DOM thusly:

```
$(".show_hide").on("click", function(event){

    $(this).next(".event-details").appendTo("#sc_events").addClass("current-event");

    return false;

});
```

My problem is that there are several more divs in the container doing the same thing. So, I need to be able to remove this appended div and when the next is clicked, the new div pops up. I got that to work like this:

```
$(".show_hide").on("click", function(event){
$(".current-event").remove();
    $(this).next(".event-details").appendTo("#sc_events").addClass("current-event");

    return false;

});
```

However, if I click back on a previously clicked item w/ the show_hide class, it doesn't return, because it's been removed using this method. I just need it to be available again.

I hope this makes sense. and thanks for the help. Here is a http://jsfiddle.net/CGySr/ that I can't get to work but has html structure more or less.

Comment: Don't forget `$(document).ready(function(){ /* Your Code */ });` Also note that your Fiddle does not include jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to make a copy of the hidden div before appending it. I also suggest using [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to prevent a potential page jump or page refresh when clicking a link.

```
$(".show_hide").on("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".current-event").hide();
  $(this).next(".event-details").clone().appendTo("#sc_events").addClass("current-event").show();
  return false;
});
```

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zaknotzak/CGySr/2/)**.

Comment: Thanks Zak for the quick response! that code is perfect but for whatever reason in my html, once a div has been appended and given the hide(); method, it does not reappear again (because it has the display none; inline).

Comment: You can use show() to make it appear. This should cause it to `display: block`. Does that work?

Comment: It's working! I must've been missing something. Thanks so much!@!